# How to create table then append to div and show the table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a table then append it to div and which should show the created table simultaneously.

This is what I have tried,

```
var content = "<table class='table1'>";
$.getJSON("/controller/Method",
{
   param1: val1
}, 
function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, value) {
     content += "<tr><td class='class1'>text1</td></tr>";
  });
  content += "</table>"
});
alert(content);

$('#div1').append(content);
```

`alert(content)` only shows `table class='table1'>`. It seems the concatenated content inside each function has not been added to `table class='table1'>`.

[`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) executes 3 times, so it should have 3 `<tr></tr>`. What is wrong with this code. Please advise.

Comment: You sure that "data" has some value, because it looks like that "data" does not have any value so it is not looping through the $.each. You can check by putting the alert("test"); within the $.each.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change for an instance.

```
var content = document.createElement('table');
$(content).addClass('table1');

var myTable = $(content);

$.getJSON("/controller/Method",
{
   param1: val1
}, 
function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, value) {
   myTable.append("<tr><td class='class1'>text1</td></tr>");
  });
});

$('#div1').append(myTable);
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write it like this (using promises). You can read more about the promise interface here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
    var table = $("<table></table>").addClass("table1");

    $.getJSON("/controller/Method",{ param1: val1 })
    .done(function(data){
      $.each(data, function (key, value) {
         table.append("<tr><td class='class1'>text1</td></tr>");
      });

    $('#div1').append(table);
   })
   .fail(function(response){
      alert("something is wrong");
   });
```

just a bit shorter :-)